# Python: How to efficiently open and read a zipfile from multiple processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-zipfile

I'm trying to open the same .zip file from multiple processes using `zipfile` and `multiprocessing`. 
When I open the .zip file using the `with zipfile.ZipFile(self.path, 'r') as archive:` syntax, the code across multiple processes works without issues, but the preformance degrades 100-fold (in some out of topic usage patterns) compared to keeping the ZipFile opened and to call read from it (guarded by `multiprocessing.Lock()` instance). 
When I use the "lock" version from multiple processes, I end up getting `zipfile.BadZipFile`exception thrown.

I don't understand why.

Here's a MNWC:

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import zipfile



class ZipFileSource(object):

    def __init__(self, path, access_mode="lock"):
        self.path = path
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        self.set_access_mode(access_mode)
        self.files = self.access( lambda archive: archive.infolist())

    def set_access_mode(self, access_mode):

        def access_lock(f):
            with self.lock:
                return f(self.archive)

        def access_file(f):
            with zipfile.ZipFile(self.path, 'r') as archive:
                return f(archive)

        if access_mode == "lock":
            print("lock")
            self.archive = zipfile.ZipFile(self.path, 'r')
            self.access = access_lock
        elif access_mode == "file":
            print("file")
            self.archive = None
            self.access = access_file



    def __del__(self):
        if self.archive is not None:
            self.archive.close()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= len(self):
            raise IndexError(f'Index {index} >= len {len(self)}')
        member = self.files[index]
        data_bytes = self.access( lambda archive: archive.read(member))
        return data_bytes


dirname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_filesource_data')

fs_small = ZipFileSource(os.path.join(dirname, 'foo_bar_small.zip'), access_mode="lock")

def read_small(i):
    return fs_small[i%len(fs_small)][42]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n_frames = 1000
    frames = np.arange(1000, dtype='u4')

    # read_small(0)


    def f(nb_processes, access_mode):

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nb_processes)
        fs_small.set_access_mode(access_mode)
        start = time.time()
        res = 0
        for i in pool.imap_unordered(read_small, frames):
            res += i
        delta = time.time() - start
        print(f"access_mode = {access_mode}, nb processes = {nb_processes}, res = {res}, {delta*1e3/len(frames)} ms/frame")
        return res

    f(1, "file")
    f(4, "file")
    f(4, "lock") 
    f(4, "lock") #crash
```

Here's my console output:

```
lock
file
access_mode = file, nb processes = 1, res = 110289, 0.08039402961730957 ms/frame
file
access_mode = file, nb processes = 4, res = 110289, 0.32297492027282715 ms/frame
lock
access_mode = lock, nb processes = 4, res = 110289, 0.2950408458709717 ms/frame
lock
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/path/to/script/test_filesource.py", line 64, in read_small
    return fs_small[i%len(fs_small)][42]
  File "/path/to/script/test_filesource.py", line 55, in __getitem__
    data_bytes = self.access( lambda archive: archive.read(member))
  File "/path/to/script/test_filesource.py", line 27, in access_lock
    return f(self.archive)
  File "/path/to/script/test_filesource.py", line 55, in <lambda>
    data_bytes = self.access( lambda archive: archive.read(member))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1337, in read
    with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1419, in open
    % (zinfo.orig_filename, fname))
zipfile.BadZipFile: File name in directory '00000005.pkl' and header b'00000004.pkl' differ.
```

You can find the zipfile used to reproduced the bug here [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue39363)

Comment: I can't tell if this question is about performance or an exception.